# Configure Specs2 to use a global connection pool

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, specs2

Currently have a project that is running Play + Play-Slick and we have issues in regards to running tests in parallel. The problem is that for every single `Specification`, it creates its own instance of a HikariCP connection pool which means that the tests end up failing with

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

You can tell this is happening because you get a lot of log messages that are saying

```
[info] - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariCP pool db is starting.
```

Since its quite a large test suite (with many specifications), using the

```
override def is = args(sequential = true) ^ super.is
```

Isn't ideal, because that will only work for the `specifications` that are a subclass of a that `specification` (however we have many specifications that are in seperate packages that have no common super type).

Is there some way to configure specs2 to use a global connection pool, so that only a single HikariCP connection pool is used for the entire testing phase

Comment: Which version of play?

Comment: Also, are you creating a connection pool per spec "method" or per specification class?

Comment: I am using Play 2.4.6. Also a connection pool is being created per specification, not per method. In beforeAll there is Play.start which is what instantiates the connection pool